# OrmLite 4.0.34 Upgrade Error

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ormlite-servicestack

This is a problem for OrmLite in Visual Studio 2013.

I just upgraded my OrmLite assemblies via NuGet from 4.0.32 to 4.0.34 and now the following line of code that gets generated with the OrmLite.SP.tt file will not work:

```
dbCommand.Transaction = OrmLiteConfig.TSTransaction!= null ? (DbTransaction)OrmLiteConfig.TSTransaction : null;
```

When I build my project, I get the following error:

```
ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConfig does not contain a definition for TSTransaction
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrmLite's T4 templates have been [updated in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/beb6b2f250d6f5ed265e00cfe0cf2265c4c686e6) to use OrmLite's latest API's.

This change is available from **v4.0.34+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).